# how to retrieve image path from database and display on to the browser using php

Tags: php, mysql

i have a search form when i click enter i has to take image from database and display on the browser.i inserted the imagepath using mysql insert commanad.
my table is

```
     +-----------+------------+-----------------------------------+
     | member_id | image_name | image_path                        |
     +-----------+------------+-----------------------------------+
     |       101 | 3k-6t      | ../images/phone_images/3k-6t.png  |
     |       102 | mirchi     | ../images/phone_images/mirchi.png |
     |       103 | masti      | ../images/phone_images/masti.png  |
     +-----------+------------+-----------------------------------+
```

tel me how to retrieve image from database.

Comment: There is no image in your database, only a path.

Comment: Based on the data above, it doesn't look like you have the image in your database - but rather, just a filename.  I would presume the files are stored in a filesystem somewhere else.

Comment: yeah now i have retrieve the image using that path

Comment: I suggest you find the code where these rows are inserted, and work back from there. It is impossible for us to say what D: is on your system.

Comment: You have not saved your path correctly either u have not escaped '\' while saving it should be like "d:\wamp*.png"

Comment: D: is just a folder where i created the folder to store the images

Comment: yeah i have to backslash..i used the front slash that is why it came like that

Answer (score 1):

Upload your file to any directory located in you site and insert path + image name in database
and then use this simple code to display your image

```
<img src="<?php echo "uploaded_directory_path+image_name"; ?>">
```

Comment: @krishnabhargavi what u try, just post it here

Answer (score 0):

If you stored path in db then using base url  just set that path in src of image tag.

and in dont store like D:/ ,In web u have to store that relative to base path of your application.

if your web applciaiton folder is mysite/. then store relative to it.and src of iamge would be www.mysite.com/(src of image form db)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to display the image in the user's browser, you can output a html page with an `<img>` tag, as proposed in a comment by [S0pra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263057/s0pra):

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<img src="<?php echo $image_path ?>">
</body>
</html>
```

If for any reason you want to send the binary image data directly to the user, the fastest way is to take the `image_path` from your database and pipe it to the output wit a simple `include` statement:

```
<?php
include $image_Path;
?>
```

I recommend setting the appropriate mime type using the [header function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) first.
Depending on your system's configuration, the image files may need to be inside a specific folder, but from what I can see with your current folder you should be fine.

But it looks as if that data of your `image_path` column is missing the path separator `\`. Be certain to call [addslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) on strings before writing them to your database.

Comment: addslashes is not used for storing values in a database. And why would you include the image from you PHP script?

Comment: Which error does it give you? Have a look at the last paragraph of my answer, I think that could be the cause...

Comment: @S0pra: It is a quick and dirty way for piping a file to the standard output, which in this case would send it to the user's browser. And why would you not use addslashes, and what would you use it for instead?

Comment: If you use a MySQL database, mysql_real_escape_string is perfectly fine. Or even better, use PDO prepared statements and you do not spend time escaping characters anymore. Regarding images, using the path (relative, though) in a `<img>` tag should be quicker.

Comment: @S0pra: You're right, it seems I misunderstood what the OP wanted to achieve - an `<img>` tag would be a much better way. Prepared statements are a good thing, I love abstracting the specific database away ;-) But I think this question warrants a more basic answer, and `addslashes` makes it easier to grasp what is going on behind the scenes, IMO.